# Why does AngularJS directive work with hardcoded values but fail with http request/response?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise, angular-directive, angular-controller

Angular Newbie Question:

I have a simple AngularJS test application that shows how a controller and a directive work together. The controller sets some hardcoded values `aB` and `aC` on the scope and the directive then displays these values in HTML. It works. Here is the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9w3rmhdL/1/). The code is below. When you run it, you can see the console output is as expected:

```
JS line #63: this.aB =  null
JS line #64: this.aC =  Goodbye
JS line #63: this.aB =  Hello
JS line #63: this.aC =  World
```

However, when I change the hardcoded values to ones that are retrieved from a test API, it fails. The console output is as follows:

```
JS line #63: this.aB =  null
JS line #64: this.aC =  Goodbye
JS line #63: this.aB =  undefined
JS line #63: this.aC =  undefined
```

The only change I made (seen here in this new [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/saqibali75/gaj3wa6x/)) was in the controller's `myFunc` function: I replaced the hardcoded values with the following:

```
  response = $http.post('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts',
    {
      'XXXXX': 'YYYYYYY'
    }
  )    
  self.scopeAB = response.id;
  self.scopeAC = response.id;
```

I have tested the API's response via `curl` and it is working fine. So why does the directive report the values of `aB` and `aC` as `undefined`? How do I solve this problem? I can tell that it has to do with the asynchronous nature of the HTTP call. But I don't know how to make this work correctly.

HTML:

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="MyCtrl as ctrl">
    <div ng-view></div>
    <ul>
      <li>{{1+1}}</li>
      <li><my-directive a-b="null" a-c="'Goodbye'"></my-directive></li>
      <li><my-directive a-b="ctrl.scopeAB" a-c="ctrl.scopeAC"></my-directive></li>
      ab = {{ctrl.scopeAB}}, ac = {{ctrl.scopeAC}}
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
```

Working Javascript:

```
myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);
myApp.directive('myDirective',function(){
    return {
      restrict:'E',
      scope: {
        aB: '=',
        aC: '='
      },
      controller: 'DirectiveCtrl',
      controllerAs: 'dirCtrl',
      bindToController: true,
      template: 'aB={{dirCtrl.aB}} aC={{dirCtrl.aC}} <input ng-model="dirCtrl.aB" />'
    };
  }
);

myApp.controller('DirectiveCtrl', function(){
    var self = this;
    console.log('this.aB = ', self.aB);
    console.log('this.aC = ', self.aC);
})

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function() {
    var self = this;
    self.myFunc = function() {
      self.scopeAB = 'Hello';
      self.scopeAC = 'World';
    }();
  }
);
```

***UPDATE:***
Claies suggested I use this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lu6zzbcx/1/). But it won't work for me because I absolutely need the values of `aB` and `aC` to be accessible in the directive's controller. I need to vary the template based on their values. This JS Fiddle seems to show them as always undefined in there.

Comment: the problem here is another piece of angular that takes a bit of explaining.  I've jumped back into the AngularJS chat channel http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63378/angularjs if you want to discuss what's going on and potential ways to deal with it.

Comment: The answer here does answer the question of why the controller values aren't updating with `$http`, but that isn't the whole picture.  As to why the directive isn't updating when the controller does, that's a different topic, one in which I feel I may have partially led you astray when discussing this topic in earlier questions.

Comment: I have updated the question based on our most recent chat conversation. But the issue remains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Claies suggested I use this JSFiddle. But it won't work for me because I absolutely need the values of aB and aC to be accessible in the directive's controller. I need to vary the template based on their values. This JS Fiddle seems to show them as always undefined in there.

If you use **@Claies** methodology, you need to put a `$watch` on the object that fires when the `$http` request resolves.

```
myApp.controller('DirectiveCtrl', function($scope){
    var self = this;
    $scope.$watch(function() {return self.scopeObject}, function (objVal) {
        console.log("watch fired");
        console.log('objVal.aB = ', objVal.aB);
        console.log('objVal.aC = ', objVal.aC);    
    },true);

});
```

The [DEMO on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bgxm7fje/).

Frankly I think you are better off following the advice from **@jumbopap**. Use the httpPromise and the `.then` method and retrieve the data from the `onFulfilled` function.

Comment: @jumbopap was mentioned in this answer.

Comment: @claies was mentioned in this answer.

Comment: georgeawg I would like to use @jumbopap's answer but I don't fully understand it because he hasn't shown a JSFiddle of it fully working.

Answer (score 2):

You should read the docs on the [$http service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http). The call is asynchronous, and you handle a successful response in the `then` callback

```
$http.post('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts', {'XXXXX': 'YYYYYYY'})
   .then(function(response) {
      self.scopeAB = response.data.id;
      self.scopeAC = response.data.id;
   })
```

Comment: That produces the same console output: https://jsfiddle.net/saqibali75/8maswfqb/1/

Comment: the answer is *mostly* correct, but when using `.then`, the response is slightly different.  I updated the answer, `response.data.id`  would be the correct usage.  However, this still doesn't make 100% sense, as this code would actually make `scopeAB` and `scopeAC` equal to the same value, which is rather odd.

Comment: Check out what the console says: `Mixed Content: The page at 'https://fiddle.jshell.net/saqibali75/8maswfqb/1/show/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.` Load the page without https.

Comment: Claies: Even after your edit, the console output remains the same: https://jsfiddle.net/saqibali75/wxx2xwg6/1/

(Yes, I know the scopeAB and scopeAC are the same. this is just for testing purposes. In my real application they will be different)

Comment: Like I said, load the page without `https` and examine the output. http://jsfiddle.net/saqibali75/wxx2xwg6/1/